# VBA recordset created from TXT file returns Null values (Excel 2013)

Tags: vba, excel, ado, recordset

I am a newbie in using recordsets in VBA and this problem drives me crazy.

I get a big report (cca 57000 rows) saved as a text file with tabs. My task is to delete unnecessary data, insert other data and create something like a pivot table. Now this task is being done manually in Excel and it produces a big file which is uncomfortable in use. So I want to import TXT file in a recordset and manipulate data with SQL statements, and save results in a separate Excel file.

I have managed to import data directly from TXT. The `.CountRecord` show the correct number of records but they are Null.
I have tried creating the recordset from `.Execute` and `.Open` with the same result.
Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub user_statistic_report()

Dim sPath As String
Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    .Properties("Data Source") = "C:\\Mydocs\raport\" 'sample path
    .Properties("Extended properties") = "text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited;"
    .Open
End With

rs.CursorLocation = 3 'someone told it helped him but it did not a trick for me
'later I'd like to select only rows with specific conditions
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [b.txt]", cn, 3
Debug.Print "Number of records:", rs.RecordCount

Set dbFields = rs.Fields
For i = 0 To dbFields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print "Column #", i, dbFields.Item(i).Name
Next i

Debug.Print "Recordset item", rs(3)

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is what I see in the Immediate window:

```
Number of records:           5<BR> 
Column #       0            F1<BR>
Column #       1            F2<BR>
Column #       2            F3<BR>
Column #       3            F4<BR>
Recordset item              Null<BR>
```

Here is my sample TXT file **b.txt**. Every line starts with a tab:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
    11  12  13
    21  22  23
```

And here is **schema.ini**:

```
[b.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
ColNameHeader=False
MaxScanRows=0
```

Could you please advise why the recordset returns Null values?

**UPDATE:**
the problem was in my TXT file, it was somehow corrupted. I have re-entered the values in the file and the script works now.

Comment: If you change `rs(3)` with `rs.RecordCount` would it give what you expect? Or with `rs(2)`, `rs(1)` or `rs(0)`. Btw this sentence is strange - *The .CountRecord show the correct number of records but they are Null.*

Comment: @Vityata, the problem is that I can retrieve the number of records with rs.RecordCount (5 records) but then all values for rs(i), rs.Fields(I) are Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you also want to print the value of the fields and not only the field names.

Modify your code like that

```
Set dbFields = rs.Fields
For i = 0 To dbFields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print "Column #", i, dbFields.Item(i).Name
Next i


rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(1).Value, rs.Fields(2).Value, rs.Fields(3).Value
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The part below will print the value of the fields.

Your issue is that you misunderstand the output of your line

```
Debug.Print "Recordset item", rs(3)
```

This line prints the value of the field number 3. It is better to write

```
Debug.Print "Recordset item", rs.fields(3).value
```

And this field might contain Null

**UPDATE** You might try the following code. You need to add a [reference to ADODB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249338.aspx#sectionSection0)

```
Option Explicit

Sub user_statistic_report()

Dim sPath As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        .Properties("Data Source") = "C:\\Mydocs\raport\"    'sample path
        .Properties("Extended properties") = "text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited;"
        .Open
    End With

    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient    'someone told it helped him but it did not a trick for me
    'later I'd like to select only rows with specific conditions
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [b.txt]", cn, adOpenStatic
    Debug.Print "Number of records:", rs.RecordCount

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    wks.UsedRange.Clear
    WriteToSheet wks, rs

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub


Sub WriteToSheet(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal rs As ADODB.Recordset)

Dim dbfields As ADODB.Fields
Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ' Write Heading resp. Field names in row 1
    Set dbfields = rs.Fields
    For i = 0 To dbfields.Count - 1
        sh.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = dbfields.Item(i).Name
    Next i

    ' Write values of the recordset starting at row 3
    j = 2
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For i = 0 To dbfields.Count - 1
            sh.Cells(j, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields.Item(i).Value
        Next i
        rs.MoveNext
        j = j + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2** That is the text file

[image]

That is the hex view

[image]

And that is the result in excel reading the file with the script

[image]

So, content of the file is

TAB 11 TAB TAB 13 CRLF

TAB 21 TAB 22 TAB 23 CRLF

TAB 31 TAB 32 TAB 33 CRLF

TAB TAB 42 TAB 43 CRLF

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately the values of elements of Fields collection still are null. I am wondering if everything is OK with my TXT file because the used algorithm seems to work for other people in Internet.

Comment: Of course you have to know the structure of your text file. One strange thing is that every line of your text file starts with a tab. That means you will get four columns and onyl three are really neccessary. And I am not sure if your fields are really separated by tabs but that is neccessary because you expect it in that way. Is there really always a tab between your fields or only at the beginning of your line? So, are there really tabs between 11  12  13?

Comment: yes, there are always tabs between my fields and every row starts with a tab (the report is generated from SAP, that's why it is so strange). I tried also to work with only one column (like A 1 2 3)but the result is the same.

Comment: Your code is working for me. I adjusted the text file. If I put two following tabs with no value into the file I will get a field with value Null what is expected. So, you might need to give more information on the contents of the file.

Comment: could you please share what adjustments have you done in the text file? I have it like this (<TAB> is for a tabifier, | for a row):

<TAB>Column1<TAB>Column2<TAB>etc|
<TAB>Value1<TAB>Value2<TAB>etc.|